# VBA run a macro when cell is changed, but not if by a macro

Tags: excel, vba

OK I'm not sure if this is easily achievable but I'm going to try.

I use this sub to execute some macros if a cell is changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim target As Range
Set target = Range("b4")
If Not Intersect(target, Range("b4")) Is Nothing Then
Call init
End If
End Sub
```

This works fine but I have a bit of a problem.

The cell `B4`, as referenced in the cell change sub above, has its value determined by a named range which is dynamic and contains a list of values on another sheet. I use the data validation tool to make `B4` a dropdown list with the contents of the named range.

I have another macro who's purpose is to update this list. What it does is clear the current list, query a database and output a bunch of values into the range. The trouble is that when this macro is run it causes the value of `B4` to change (as `B4` references the values in the range). This in turn cause my "cell change" macro to run throwing up errors.

Is there a way to prevent the "cell change" macro from running while I'm updating the list that it references?

Hope that question makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable the `Worksheet_Calculate` Events by using `Application.EnableEvents` as below. Please note this will disable any `WorkSheet` or `WorkBook` event that may occur in-between `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True`

So if your other sub was run like this - the `Worksheet_Calculate` event won't fire

```
Sub Other_Sub()
Application.EnableEvents = False
[b4].Value = "10"
'other stuff
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that is probably a more elegant and robust solution than my own - it also makes my code run much faster!

Comment: An even better approach would be to store the current value of `Application.EnableEvents` in a boolean variable and set it back to that value at the end, rather than setting it to `True`, so that events aren't toggled on/off when a sub calls another sub

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I have worked out a simple solution:
Just put a conditional statement in saying to not execute "init" if B4 contains an error or is blank.

Answer (score 1):

and be aware of (exit sub) or (exit function)... 
Don't forget to use Application.EnableEvents = True before (exit sub) or (exit function) commands (if exists)

Comment: Probably best to have error catching as well in case the macro is interrupted