# How do I run a macro when the enter key is pressed on a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm currently trying to create a tool that will call/run another macro/sub when the enter key is pressed on cell B4.

Cell B4 will be the search field. Whenever someone types something in this field and hits enter on their keyboard I want another macro called "searchcontains" to run

I've tried using this code but I'm not sure how to specifically define the B3 cell:

Application.OnKey "~", "searchcontains"

Comment: You can look at the `Worksheet_Change` event

Comment: https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm 
 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267850/vba-run-a-macro-when-cell-is-changed-but-not-if-by-a-macro?rq=1) pretty much uses the exact code you should need, except that you probably want the Worksheet_change ofc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code:
1. Open VBA Editor
2. Go to the Worksheet VBA Editor
3. Select Worksheet and Change Event
4. Copy the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row = 4 And Target.Column = 2 Then
    'The function will be called only if the cell has a value
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value <> "" Then
       'Call the function here
       Call sample_function(ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value)
    End If
End If

End Sub



Sub sample_function(input_String As String)

MsgBox "You input: " & input_String, vbInformation

End Sub
```